# 90s kids TV Movie about finding valuable artifact or treasure

Tags: identify-this-movie

Been trying to remember this one for a little while now. Have attempted a few times to find this online but have had little to no luck.

- **Estimated year of film:** 90s
- **Setting:** Coastal region America / UK
- **Language:** English
- **Main character:** Dark haired boy
- **Type:** TV Movie

My memory of the film itself is very thin but I do remember a few key plots and one particular scene.

The kid in the film has a vast knowledge about submarines and other maritime vessels mainly WW2 types maybe. Unknown back story but believe he moved to the area recently.

A longish haired bad guy is involved and they both end up in pursuit of valuable lost artefacts or treasure.

**Key Scene:**

At the end of the film the bad guys and the boy find what there looking for. As the main bad guy goes to do something a torpedo slides down from the ceiling and stops in front of him. Then a puff of gas comes out the end of it, possibly some sort of nerve agent. The real sticking point was the bad guy violently foaming at the mouth as the nerve gas effectively kills him.

**Additional Details:** The film takes place in modern times. I believe the kid had a friend, possibly female (very unsure). It was live-action, not animated.

Unfortunately I have no further information but if anyone knows the film be great to find it again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [Mystic Nights and Pirate Fights](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0138640/combined) from 1998.

> Young Jonah Johnson and his family move into Mystic, CT. The town's local fisherman's son, Schooner, quickly befriends him and the two soon discover what seems to be a 300-year-old treasure map. The treasure of Captain Kidd that was lost in the town 3 decades earlier. While trying to evade the town's bullies, Jonah and Schooner keep their eye on Clive Steelway, a rich treasure-seeker who seems to have conniving plans for the treasure and the boys.

Jonah knows a lot about submarines (his father is a sumbarine commander). In the end, they all reach the treasure and Clive's demise is exactly is as you described: Once he grabs the treasure, a torpedo slides down from the ceiling releasing green gas, causing him to foam at the mouth and apparently killing him. The scene briefly appears in the trailer around 1:17:

Comment: Walt you're a legend! Well done for finding it :)  And the trailer has all the bits I remember too. Thank you!